# Is it possible to use models in laravel routes without static?

Tags: php, laravel

For example I need to return comments. I already have a method for this in my `model`. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Route::get('/comments/{page}', function($page) {
    $comments = Comments::get($page);
    return Response::json($comments);
});
```

Or do I need to create a facade for each `model`?

Comment: Looks okay to me, have you tried doing that yet or gotten any errors from doing it this way?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. I cannot figure what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

Typically, comments would be associated with a page via an Eloquent relationship, which would allow something like this:

```
return Response::json($page->comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Defining A Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) on `Laravel` website:

```
// In Comments Model
public function scopeGetMessage($query, $page)
{
    // You can use $query->where(...)
    // return the query for chaining

    // You can use $this->where(...)
    // Or just return the thing you want
}
```

Now you may call it like:

```
$comments = Comments::getMessage($page);
```